# How to grab functions from python files, inside a certain folder structure

Tags: python, import

I am starting up a project and am going to build multiple webscrapers. For this I want to build a few generic functions but also maintain good folder structure. Currently it looks like this.

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BSp9.png)

When I run tourney_scraper.py, which has the code line:`from Utils.test import test`

It gives an No module named Utils error

Is there any way to solve this or if someone has a better best practice. I would love to hear it :)

Comment: The most convenient structure is to have your main programs are in the root, and your utilities are in a subfolder.  Now your main program can add its own folder to `sys.path`, and the subfolders become modules.  Personally, I'm not a fan of the numeric prefixes, like `01_src`.

Comment: `__init__.py` should probably go in the src folder.
I'd also recommend you to have a main.py file right inside 01_src. That's the file you should be running.
Then the import in main.py will be `import Tourney.01_code.tourney_scraper`.